# Json - array or something else?

Tags: javascript

I have a webservice which result data in json

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:50015/WebService1.asmx/json_Getdata",
        data: '{}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnSuccess,
        failure: function (response) {
            debugger;
            alert(response.d);
        },
        error: function (response) {
            debugger;
            alert(response.d);
        }
    });
});

function OnSuccess(response) {
    var records = response.d;
    records[0].name
    debugger;
}
```

It giving response in below format

> [  {"id": "1","name": "Mr. xyz","Age": "25","Country":
>   "India","Address": "H no- 4561","Phone": "1258961"}, {"id":
>   "2","name": "Mr. xyz","Age": "26","Country": "India","Address": "H no-
>   4562","Phone": "1258962"}, {"id": "3","name": "Mr. xyz","Age":
>   "27","Country": "India","Address": "H no- 4563","Phone": "1258963"},
>   {"id": "4","name": "Mr. xyz","Age": "28","Country": "India","Address":
>   "H no- 4564","Phone": "1258964"}, {"id": "5","name": "Mr. xyz","Age":
>   "29","Country": "India","Address": "H no- 4565","Phone": "1258965"} ]

As per my understanding it is an array and  records[0].name should have a name value but it is always undefined also records.length =749 which is i dont know how come. 
can some tell me how to use this data by index (in for loop)?

Comment: Learn to use `console.log()` instead of `alert()`

Comment: please test if JSON.parse work..

[link](https://jsfiddle.net/8L8o0v2a/)

Comment: why do you use `response.d` ? isn't it `response.data` ?

Comment: @DimitriL. i checked , inside response their is only _proto_ and d

Comment: @FrankWisniewski thanks , it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Try `var records = response;` if your response is as it is given.
2. Try validating your JSON response.